# Using "They are" vs. Using "He is" multiple times

Tags: sentence-construction, pronouns

> Q : Who are they?

Which answer is correct in grammar?

> A1: They are Roy, Ryo, And Ory.
>   A2: He is Roy, he is Ryo, and he is Ory.

Comment: Despite being grammatical, the second sentence is clumsy because of the overuse of the same pronoun. Although it would be understandable (and perhaps common)  if it were dialogue, and the narrative indicated somebody pointing to different people while saying it, if it's just a descriptive sentence, it's a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

They are both grammatically correct, but used in slightly different ways.
In the first alternative, you're treating them as a group, but in the second you're pointing to them individually.

Compare it to

> A1: They are Simon and Garfunkel
>
> A2: He is Simon and he is Garfunkel